# Rails - How to add color and size (choices or input) from a user of a product to my cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a simple e-commerce store. I am using Rails admin to upload each product with basic information such as :title, :photo, :description and :price. Each Product when selected is added to a Cart and then to an Order.

What I would like to do, is that when a user is picking a product; That they are able to select their chosen **size** and the **color** they want the product in. I was wondering how to do this, since I would need the users input.

Ive tried creating a form and rendering it on the product to add these options. Would anyone know about any other alternatives?

I also tried creating a **Select** form on my **Product/Index:**

```
 <select name="product[size]" id="product_quantity"><option value="size"></option>
                       <option selected="selected" value="1">XS</option>
                       <option value="2">S</option>
                       <option value="3">M</option>
                       <option value="4">L</option>
                       <option value="5">XL</option></select>
```

But I cant get the users input to display on my order.

I also read about creating **product variants** but I don't know how to implement this...

This is my index.html.erb Product views

```
<section class="product-list">
   <div class="container">
      <% @product.each do |product| %>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="product">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                     <div class="thumbnail">
                        <%= cl_image_tag product.photo %>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
                     <div class="product-details">
                        <h2 class="product-title"> <a href=""><%= link_to product.title, product %></h2>
                        <p class="product-price"><%= number_to_currency product.price %></p>
                        <p><%= product.description %></p>
                        <%= button_to product_items_path(product_id: product.id), class: 'btn btn-default' do %>
                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to cart
                        <% end %>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->
      <% end %>
   </div>
</section>
```

My schema:

```
create_table "active_admin_comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "namespace"
    t.text "body"
    t.string "resource_type"
    t.bigint "resource_id"
    t.string "author_type"
    t.bigint "author_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["author_type", "author_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_author_type_and_author_id"
    t.index ["namespace"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_namespace"
    t.index ["resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_resource_type_and_resource_id"
  end

  create_table "admin_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_admin_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_admin_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  create_table "carts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "contacts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.text "message"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.text "address"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "country"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "shipped", default: false
  end

  create_table "product_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "product_id"
    t.bigint "cart_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "quantity", default: 1
    t.bigint "order_id"
    t.index ["cart_id"], name: "index_product_items_on_cart_id"
    t.index ["order_id"], name: "index_product_items_on_order_id"
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_product_items_on_product_id"
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "photo"
    t.text "description"
    t.decimal "price"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "size"
    t.string "size2"
  end

  add_foreign_key "product_items", "carts"
  add_foreign_key "product_items", "orders"
  add_foreign_key "product_items", "products"
end
```

Comment: Make the user selected options attributes on the `ProductItem` model.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response!

I am new to Rails so I am having a bit of trouble with this. Could you give me an example of how to make the user selected option attributes?